# Поиск по базе по нескольким критериям

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, like

Нужно сформировать `sql` запрос. Условия такие: сортировка по категории и по цвету, но т.к обе эти категории сохранены в базе функцией `serialize` нужно дописывать в запрос `like` никак не могу понять как сделать сразу 2 `like` в одном запросе

```
public static function getPickingProduct($category, $color) {
        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, price, id_shop, sale, name_img FROM product WHERE category LIKE :txt AND colors LIKE :colors AND path <> 'not-show'";
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute( [':txt' => "%{$category}%", ':colors' => "{$color}"] );
        return $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том что я не поставил `%%` в биндинг
Было так: `$sth->execute( [':txt' => "%{$category}%", ':colors' => "{$color}"] );`
А надо было так: `$sth->execute( [':txt' => "%{$category}%", ':colors' => "%{$color}%"] );`

Comment: мы всегда рады вам помочь ;)